# Can I install Starcraft 2 multiplayer only, without campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have installed WoL, size 14 GB, when I buy HotS I'm afraid that might grow up to 30 GB, which is too much. Since I'm not going to play campaign, is there an option to install online multiplayer only?

Comment: 14 Gb is the size of HotS. The whole game is installed, even if you do not have the latest license. This way you can play instantly after you upgrade, and also your HotS-owning friend can come and play his HotS.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, unfortunately you cannot pick and choose. However, HotS was less than 5GB for me, you should be fine.

EDIT: I did digital download, IDK if a physical copy is bigger/smaller.