# Is it possible to reduce Starcraft 2's disk footprint?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to minimize disk space usage?

---

I only want to play multiplayer anyway and the biggest chunk of the download is the campaign.

Since the multiplayer game is playable after only 10% of the whole download, I am wandering if one could simply stop it there somehow?

**Update:**
It seems you can delete some folders and save lots of GB: https://web.archive.org/web/20120211041635/http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/1776589198

I tried this, but the folders I deleted are immediately re-downloaded at the next start via Battlenet. Maybe you have to start it differently?

Can you create a batch script that does the job?

What about updates? Is this even possible without repairing those missing folders?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has to be against the terms-and-conditions

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't be against the terms and conditions, if you move large parts of the game to an external drive with symbolic links using the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#download)? Then you could still update the game with the external HD attached, but play it without.

Comment: @Ender After skimming through the EULA, I can't see how this would violate any part of it. VTLO.

Comment: Move it, then locate it.

Comment: VTLO? what does this mean

Comment: VTLO = Vote to Leave Open, btw

Comment: This would be better asked by a GM on Battle.net under the Starcraft 2 forums/ticket system.

Comment: Your best bet is to go with [symbolic links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the folders you want to move. That will make sure the launcher finds the files but they aren't located on the smaller HD.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe you could create empty versions of the folders in question, and then make them Read-Only, enforceable through admin? It's possible the game simply wouldn't start up after that, but it's worth a try.

Comment: The link you've quoted there under "Update" is 404 now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have enough space on your internal drive follow these steps:

1. install StarCraft 2 on an external drive and once it reaches the first step where it says "optimal" in green you pause the download.
2. If you don't want to use your external drive every time you play, you can move the install folder now to your internal drive
3. search in the battle.net client for the Folder where you moved it and resume download but pause at the optimal green step again.

This way you only need about 5gb

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible, everytime you open the game, the game will check for updates, will check your files, and if they dont match it will download/redownload them (to avoid corruption/keep you up to date). If you try to erase some folders, you will most likely end up with a corrupt installation. I suggest you try erasing something else from your computer.

Even if you managed to erase those files, everytime you open your game launcher updates would download those files again, and you will need the space for the game anyways in order to play.

Comment: Did you try replacing large files in the campaign folder with 0 byte dummy files?

Comment: Deleting something else is ridiculous. Many people only have 60 GB for their windows installation total on their SSD

Comment: the game clearly states that it needs 20GB for storage as minimum requirement.

Comment: Sure, but if we manage to find a solution for users with only small SSDs we could open the fun of Starcraft to many more players

Comment: @rubo77: You say that like you can't play without an SSD... :)

Comment: I am talking about notebooks.

Comment: replacing files with dummies wont work, the updater has no way of telling if the modifications are harmful or not (you trying to hack the game or you doing something else) so they would get checked and redownloaded to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no official way neither i can find anything about deleting folders to keep size small. There was a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/can-i-install-starcraft-2-multiplayer-only-without-campaign) a year ago and it seems this hasn't changed for now. So there is no way to install the multiplayer only.